# Select model is lost when rendering a zone

Tags: java, tapestry

I have an issue while updating the render on a select field with Tapestry.

I want to disable 2 fields (1 textfield and 1 select field) depending of what I selected in another field (also a select field). I want to render the disabled fields immediately so I am using the Tapestry Zone system to do so.

However I keep getting the following exception for the select field when I select an item from the "fruitOrVegetableSelect" list :

```
Parameter 'model' of component fruit/Edit:fruitNames is bound to null. This parameter is not allowed to be null.
```

Here is my code in the tml page :

```
<t:zone t:id="fruitsForEveryOneZone" update="show">
            <tr>
                <td> <t:select
                    t:id="fruitName" t:model="fruitNames"
                    value="fruit?.fruitName" 
             disabled="getDisabledFruitField()" />
                </td>
                
                <td><t:textfield t:id="numberOfFruits"
                    value="fruit?.quantity"
                    disabled="getDisabledFruitField()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
</t:zone>
```

And here is the code in the controller :

```
@OnEvent(component = "fruitOrVegetableSelect", value = EventConstants.VALUE_CHANGED)
public Object updateFruitOrVegetable(Plant plant)
{
    if (plant.getName().equals("Fruit"){
        this.disabledFruitField=false;
    else {
        this.disabledFruitField=true;
    }
    return new MultiZoneUpdate("fruitsForEveryOneZone", fruitsForEveryOneZone.getBody());
}
```

If I limit the zone so it only takes the textfield input it works fine (except that my select is never disabled). For some reason the "model" from my select field is lost in the process. Any idea why this happens and how I can avoid this problem?

Answer (score -1):

This code is not showing how "fruitNames" is declared in java class. I guess that "fruitNames" is a variable and it's just lost. You should annotate "fruitNames" with `@Persist` and this should do the trick or declare "fruitNames" as a method (`getFruitNames()`).